# MS Project 2010 -> SharePoint 2010 tasks

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tasks, ms-project

When syncing MS Project plan to SharePoint task list my Notes field is truncated to 255 characters.

Is there a way of syncing >255 characters in the MS Project plan "Notes" field (or some other custom field) into a multiple line of text column in the SharePoint task list?